# Customizing what url_for returns for a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, actionview

I have a `post` model that has many `comments`.  Now a link to a comment is actually a url like so `/post/1?page=3#26`.

What I want to be able to do is call `link_to "foobar", @comment` and have it generate the correct url.  I already know how to calculate the page a comment is on so you can assume `@comment.page_num` will return the correct integer.

I think this is going to require customizing the [`polymorphic_url`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) somehow.

If it can't easily be done maybe I need a helper function `link_to_comment` but I'd like it to be able to do everything `link_to` can, ie passing blocks and what not.

Comment: You might be able to do something by overriding to_param, but that will still require you to pass the post_id into link_to. Here's some info https://gist.github.com/1209732

Comment: I think it's more then the to_param, the url is entirely different.  I had thought about just doing some url redirecting though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I ended up doing.  It pretty simple but does exactly what I need.  My original scope might have been too ambitious.  Classic case of *keep it simple stupid*.

```
module CommentsHelper

  def comment_page_url(comment)
    post_url(comment.post, page: comment.page_num, anchor: comment.id)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work:

```
link_to "foobar", @post, href: "#{url_for(@post)}?page=#{@comment.page_num}"
```

This is assuming that `page_num` returns `3#26` which is an assumption I'm not terribly confident about, but I think you can figure it out from there.

One more comment to think about. Is `page_num` really a vital attribute of the `Comment` class? It seems to me that it's a formatting concern and probably belongs in a helper function instead of the `Model`. Just something to think about.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Why aren't you passing page as a param?  Also I pretty much knew how to do this already, I was hoping to override something so that url_for(@comment) would generate the url with out having to pass in anything else.

Comment: I put page_num on the model because that is where kaminari puts them.  I think because pagination can be used for more then just displaying in the view.